# jquery.ptTimeSelect.js how to show the popup above the input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timepicker

I am using jquery.ptTimeSelect.js as timepicker.
It defaults to show the time popup right below the input field.
Is there a way to change it/set it up, so that the popup show **above** the input field?

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("#InputId").ptTimeSelect({
    onBeforeShow: function(inputFieldAsJQuery, widgetAsJQuery){
        widgetAsJQuery.css(
            "top",
            parseInt(widgetAsJQuery.css("top")) - widgetAsJQuery.height() - 20 + "px"
        );
    }
});
```

If for some reason this does not work or is glitchy, then move the content of the delegate into a "setTimeout()"